# How to ping to my local machine from AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have started an ubuntu instance on AWS EC2

```
e.g. [ec2-user@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX ~]$
```

Inside this instance, I am running a socket program for sending the data to my local system.
The program is running properly, but not able to connect to my local IP.

I am trying to ping my local system also from `AWS ec2` user, but it is also not working.But I am able to `ping google(8.8.8.8)`.

```
e.g. [ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ ping xxx.xxx.xx.xx(my local IP)
```

I have set all security groups(inbound), like All Trafic,All TCP and so on.

Sorry for bad English.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Your computer (PC) cannot be pinged from an AWS hosted machine

This is probably because the VM on your computer is using NAT outbound to talk to the LAN, which goes to an Internet router, which sends the packets to AWS
The reverse route (inbound to your PC) does not exist so starting a ping echo request from a AWS machine will not work

It is possible to get around this by opening a pass through on your router but generally this is not a great idea

However if you want to make a socket connection securely there is a way

First, start a ssh session with remote port forwarding.  In the Linux ssh client this is using the -R option.

For example, if your local system is running a listening service on port 80 and your remote system has the address of 54.10.10.10 then

```
ssh -R 8080:localhost:80 ec2-user@54.10.10.10
```

Will establish a circuit such that connections to the "localhost" on the remote ec2 server on port 8080 are connected to the "localhost" on port 80 of your local machine

If you are not using a ssh cli program, most ssh clients have a facility of this sort.

Note that it is necessary to keep the ssh session open to be able to use the connections

Comment: Thank You, Sir, but actually, on my local system I am running my server(server.java) which will receive the data and I want to send the data from AWS using a cpp client (client.cpp). Is it possible to do so?

Comment: The link is broken.